# Strange text field behaviour with flash

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash

Here is my code:

```
    <% if flash.now[:error] %>
        <div id='login-error'>
            <p id='error-text'><%= flash.now[:error] %></p>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <% if flash.now[:error] %>

    <%= label_tag :email %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, class: "error"%>

    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password, class: "error" %>

    <% else %>

    <%= label_tag :email %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email%>

    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password%>

    <% end %>
```

When there is a validation error for the session the actual class name 'error' appears in the text field when the new page with the flash is rendered. The class is not applied, but the actual class name appears within both the text and password fields. Any clue why this is happening?

Specifically, this is what appears in the email field: {:class=>"error"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works any better (note the `nil` arguments):

```
<%= label_tag :email %>
<%= text_field_tag :email, nil, class: "error" %>

<%= label_tag :password %>
<%= password_field_tag :password, nil, class: "error" %>
```

For these particular form helpers, the options hash has to be the third argument. The second argument actually sets the input field's value.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working, however the application of the class doesn't seem to be persisting through re-directs. There's a brief flash of the application of the class (background to red, then it disappears). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what that would be from. Is the `#login-error` division persisting, or does it also disappear? Do you have any jQuery acting on page load?